# Integral over product of Dirac delta functions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

We can define the Dirac Delta function as a distribution satisfying

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{d}x\; \delta(x-a)\; f(x) = f(a) .\tag{1}$$

What if I have a product of delta functions?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{d}x\; \delta(a-x)\; \delta(x-b)\; f(x) =~? \tag{2}$$

Comment: This is $0$ if $a \neq b$.

Comment: What if $a = b$?

Answer (score 2):

OP's expression (2) makes sense in [distribution theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)):
$$\color{blue}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x\; \delta(a-x)\; \delta(x-b)\; f(x) ~=~\delta(a-b)\; f(b)}.\tag{A}$$
*Proof:* If we apply a test function $g\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to both sides
$$\begin{align}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\!\mathrm{d}a\;\mathrm{d}b\;g(a,b)\color{blue}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x\; \delta(a-x)\; \delta(x-b)\; f(x)} 
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x\; g(x,x)\; f(x)\cr
~=~&\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\!\mathrm{d}a\;\mathrm{d}b\;g(a,b)\;\color{blue}{\delta(a-b)\; f(b)},\tag{B}\end{align}$$
they yield the same result. $\Box$

In other words, the LHS and RHS of eq. (A) is a notation for the same distribution $u\in{\cal D}^{\prime} (\mathbb{R}^2)$ given by $$u[g]~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x\; g(x,x)\; f(x). \tag{C}$$

Comment: Hi! Does it mean that $\int \delta^2(x-a) f(x) dx \ne f(a)$? Because somewhere on the forum I saw a post that the square of a delta function acts the same as just delta with a strict proof. So it is kinda confusing that the case $a=b$ is a somewhat special case.

Comment: In OP's distribution (2) the variables $a$ and $b$ are [indeterminates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)), not fixed numbers.