# How can I compute the integral of the product of two Dirac delta and a polynomial?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}dk~k^{d-2}\delta(k-a)\delta(k-b).$$

I tried substituting $k^{d-2}\delta(k-a)$ with other espressions such as  $\frac{d}{dk}\biggl[k^{d-2}\Theta(k-a)\biggr]-(d-2)k^{d-3}\Theta(k-a)$ and integrating by parts but it doesn't lead to the solution.

Comment: What is the context? Are you sure you have the right expression?

Comment: If $a \ne b$, the integral is just zero.

Comment: As others have noted, if $a\not=b$, the literal functional/integral is $0$. But, in contrast to some claims, if $a=b$ it is simply undefined, in a strong sense, since $\delta^2$ "is not a thing". This leads me to strongly wonder whether you're really asking the question you intend to ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) simplifies to
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathrm{d}k~\theta(k)~k^{d-2}~\delta(a-k)~\delta(k-b)~=~\theta(a)~a^{d-2}~\delta(a-b),$$
cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3400797/11127) related Math.SE post.

Comment: Okay, you are right.  Didn't see that the integral's lower limit is zero, so we need to include a step function.  Otherwise our answers agree.

Answer (score 0):

The contribution of the integrand is zero wherever $k\ne a$ or $k \ne b$.  If $a\ne b$, then the integral is zero.

If $a=b \ge 0$, then the integral is equal to $b^{d-2}$ else zero.  Thanks to @Qmechanic for pointing that out (essentially a step function multiplying this term).