# Products of Dirac delta distributions in multiple dimensions

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

Following up on [Integral over product of Dirac delta functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3400797/integral-over-product-of-dirac-delta-functions), I have the following generalization of the question (arising from a problem in quantum mechanics):

**If I have the product of two Dirac delta distributions with *non-identical* arguments**
$$\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\langle r_{rel} r_{cm} \vert r_1 r_2 \rangle 
    = \delta\big( (r_1-r_2) - r_{rel} \big) \times \delta\big( \tfrac12 (r_1+r_2) - r_{cm} \big),
$$
**can I somehow argue that it is "equivalent" to the alternate form**
$$\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
\langle r_1 r_2 \vert r_{rel} r_{cm} \rangle 
    = \delta\big( (r_{cm} + \tfrac12 r_{rel}) - r_1 \big) \times \delta\big( (r_{cm} - \tfrac12 r_{rel}) - r_2 \big) ?$$
(Note here that we can consider these as representing the change of variables $(r_1,r_2)\rightarrow(r_{rel},r_{cm})$ and $(r_{rel},r_{cm})\rightarrow(r_1,r_2)$, respectively.)

---

If I try to show that these two forms are equivalent by, e.g., integrating against test functions, I either end up with an integration variable appearing in the argument to two of the delta distributions or with some reordering of integration which I'm not sure I can justify. (In that sense, this may also be a question about Fubini's theorem in the theory of distributions.)

For instance, integrating each of these against the test functions $f(r_1,r_2)$, $g(r_{rel},r_{cm})$, I get
$$\tag{3}\label{eq:1int}
\int dr_1\, dr_2 \int dr_{rel}\, dr_{cm} \, f(r_1,r_2) g(r_{rel},r_{cm}) \delta\big( (r_1-r_2) - r_{rel} \big) \delta\big( \tfrac12 (r_1+r_2) - r_{cm} \big) \\= \int dr_1 \, dr_2 \, f(r_1,r_2) g(r_1-r_2, \tfrac12(r_1+r_2))
$$
$$\tag{4}\label{eq:2int}
\int dr_{rel}\, dr_{cm} \int dr_1\, dr_2 \, f(r_1,r_2) g(r_{rel},r_{cm}) \delta\big( (r_{cm} + \tfrac12 r_{rel}) - r_1 \big) \delta\big( (r_{cm} - \tfrac12 r_{rel}) - r_2 \big) \\= \int dr_{rel} \, dr_{cm} \, f(r_{cm}+\tfrac12 r_{rel},r_{cm}-\tfrac12 r_{rel}) g(r_{rel},r_{cm})
$$

---

1. Is it a problem that I'm doing the multiple integrals in a different order between $\eqref{eq:1int}$ and $\eqref{eq:2int}$ if I want to show the equivalence of $\eqref{eq:1}$ and $\eqref{eq:2}$?
2. Is it sufficient to do the somewhat trivial change of variables $(r_1,r_2)\rightarrow (r_{rel},r_{cm})$ on $\eqref{eq:1int}$ to show that it is equal to $\eqref{eq:2int}$, and is that sufficient to establish the equality/equivalence of $\eqref{eq:1}$ and $\eqref{eq:2}$?

Comment: Good question, I had a similar concern when using Green's function in polar or spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let us for concreteness consider a 3D position space $\mathbb{R}^3$. (The generalization to other dimensions is straightforward.) Consider position operators $\hat{\bf r}_1$ and $\hat{\bf r}_2$ for 2 non-identical particles.
2. In a [rigged Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) we define eigenkets
   $$|{\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2\rangle, \tag{1} $$
   such that
   $$ \hat{\bf r}_1 |{\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2\rangle~=~{\bf r}_1|{\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2\rangle, \qquad 
   \hat{\bf r}_2 |{\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2\rangle~=~{\bf r}_2|{\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2\rangle, \tag{2}$$
   and
   $$ \langle {\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2 | {\bf r}^{\prime}_1,{\bf r}^{\prime}_2\rangle
   ~=~\delta^3({\bf r}_1\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime}_1)\delta^3({\bf r}_2\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime}_2) .\tag{3}$$
3. Define operators
   $$ \hat{\bf r}_{\rm cm}~:=~\frac{\hat{\bf r}_1+\hat{\bf r}_2}{2},\qquad \hat{\bf r}_{\rm rel}~:=~\hat{\bf r}_1-\hat{\bf r}_2, \tag{4} $$
   and corresponding kets
   $$|{\bf r}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}_{\rm rel}\rangle\!\rangle~:=~|{\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2\rangle, \qquad 
   {\bf r}_{\rm cm}~\equiv~\frac{{\bf r}_1+{\bf r}_2}{2},\qquad 
   {\bf r}_{\rm rel}~\equiv~{\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2. \tag{5} $$
4. One may use eqs. (2), (3), (4) & (5) to show that the kets (5) are eigenkets
   $$ \hat{\bf r}_{\rm cm} |{\bf r}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}_{\rm rel}\rangle\!\rangle~=~{\bf r}_{\rm cm}|{\bf r}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}_{\rm rel}\rangle\!\rangle, \qquad 
   \hat{\bf r}_{\rm rel} |{\bf r}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}_{\rm rel}\rangle\!\rangle~=~{\bf r}_{\rm rel}|{\bf r}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}_{\rm rel}\rangle\!\rangle, \tag{6}$$
   and normalized
   $$ \langle\!\langle {\bf r}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}_{\rm rel} | {\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm rel}\rangle\!\rangle
   ~=~\delta^3({\bf r}_{\rm cm}\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm cm})\delta^3({\bf r}_{\rm rel}\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm rel}). \tag{7}$$
   In eq. (7) we used how higher-dimensional Dirac delta distributions transform under coordinate transformations, cf. e.g. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/619471/11127). It is important that the Jacobian of the transformation (4) is one.
5. Similarly, one may show that the overlap is
   $$ \langle {\bf r}_1,{\bf r}_2 | {\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm cm},{\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm rel}\rangle\!\rangle
   ~=~\delta^3(\frac{{\bf r}_1+{\bf r}_2}{2}\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm cm})\delta^3({\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime}_{\rm rel}), \tag{8}$$
   etc.

Comment: How does this definition imply that the two forms of the overlap are equivalent, though? In one case, we have $r_1$ and $r_2$ appearing in the arguments of both deltas, while in the other we have $r_{rel}$ and $r_{cm}$ appearing in the arguments to both. I think I'm still missing something...

Comment: I updated the answer.